# How to use a html page in here which seems to be bootstrap Laravel

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, laravel-9

In here the "Welcome to Webshooter"-part https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0FJq.jpg
has this code: (dashboard.blade.php)

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
                {{_('Welcome to Webshooter')}}
        </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p>Webshooter is a tool that facilitates the management of competitions for your association and you as a member.</p>
                <p>Our experience says that there are a few tools that are suitable for complete management of competitions, registered participants and result lists. Although local installations, spreadsheets of various formats and foreign web solutions satisfy basic needs, we are convinced that a common portal is the right solution.</p>
                <p>Webshooter development takes place on an ongoing basis in the order in which users request functions. No matter what you have on your mind that you want to share with us or that you are wondering about, we would like you to get in touch. We answer all questions and concerns that come to us!</p>
                <h4>We warmly welcome you!</h4>
            </div>
    </div>
```

It seems to be some sort of bootstrap-code.
Now, I want to replace this with a HTML-page showing a map but how to do that?
I want to keep the menu-bar to be able to chose from.
It's a Laravel9 project.

I have put this code into the page instead of the "Welcome to Webshooter"-part: (taken from here: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7644920)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d19vzq90twjlae.cloudfront.net/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script src="https://d19vzq90twjlae.cloudfront.net/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
    </script>

    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
        mapLink = 
            '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
        L.tileLayer(
            'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
But I'm getting no map. It looks that it reserve space for the map.
It seems that the script's doesn't work for some reason.
```

Comment: Please share the code you are currently using, along with your attempts to resolve the problem. Why not simply edit the template?

Comment: Look above, tried with a simple working example but it don't show any map.

Comment: I succeeded to show the map after I logged out and logged in again. But if I refresh the browser it disappears.